# Instagram API real time updates of likes and comments

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I read the new documentation for Instagram subscriptions [API](http://instagram.com/developer/subscriptions).
It says that after you subscribe, Instagram will notify you when people post new media on their page.

I would like to be notified when one of the user's post receive a new like or a comment?

Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Instagram API` does not currently support this option.

From the User Subscription Page:

> User subscriptions are useful if you want to be notified when people who authenticated your app **post new media on Instagram**.

You will get a POST request only when there is a new post, it will not notify for likes or comments.

Comment: So in order to get updates for the user's post, I have to manually pull data from instagram using post id? I know about the '/media/media-id' endpoint. I wanted to ask you if there's  a solution to get updates for a set of ids and not make a instagram request for each of the users id ?

Comment: @Catalin AFAIK that option doesn't exist either and you will need to send a request for each id.